# GPS (gnat) does't show the tags in a source file

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

[image: show tags] [image: doesn't show the tags]

**Question 1**

In the first image, you can see that GNAT Programming Studio is showing tags (package, pragma, subprogram, etc.) for the file `wasabee-caches.adb`

In the second image, however, GPS won't let me expand directory `.` (the current directory, highlighted in blue), is this by design or I misconfigured something?

**Question 2**

In the second project, Wasabee_GWindows, when I try to `gnatpp` (Menubar: Edit/Pretty Print) a source file, GPS told me *gnat: aggregate library projects are not supported*, my question is, how do I pretty print a source file in Wasabee_GWindows? (The AWS is aggregate, Wasabee_GWindows's gpr file has `with "aws"`, but Wasabee_GWindows's gpr file itself doesn't have something like `aggregate library project Wasabee_GWindows` in it. The project compiles OK.)

Comment: If you can't expand a directory, it's because there are no source files in that directory.

Comment: @egilhh It has source files in it, several `.adb` and '.ads' files.

Comment: Then it could depend on your naming scheme, or whether "Ada" is listed as a language in the project file (for Languages use ("Ada");)

Comment: No, just checked, no luck.

Comment: Can you post the project file?

Comment: And do you get any errors in GPS (red text in the Messages window) when opening the project?

Comment: If you are really interested, I can pack the whole thing and upload it to somewhere, so you can see it.

Comment: Sure, the project is taken from wasabee.sourceforge.net, (svn: r263, zrt_dev), you can get my modified gpr file at pastebin.com/mrg35nr2, the AWS (Ada Web Server) project is taken from it's official git repo `git clone --recursive http://forge.open-do.org/anonscm/git/aws/aws.git`, I am using GPL 2014 on Windows. No, no error showed in GPS.